# Booking Calendar add-on With Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

Only displays 10 events on my Google Form. How do you display all events.

No options to display more events.

Support forums required for development and support. Facebook group appears in active since 2018.

Any resources the official website https://bc.vietutd.com is not exactly comprehensive.